# MS Access VBA: The 'Docmd.RunCommand AcCmdOutputToExcel' function has recently stopped working

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have used this built-in MS Access function, 'Docmd.RunCommand AcCmdOutputToExcel' in VBA for years in many databases at many sites. This code has now, just recently stopped working.  Has anyone else run into this issue with MS Access 2016-2019 or 365?

Here is an example of my code. It runs by clicking a command button on a form:

```
    Private Sub Command4_Click()
    On Error GoTo C4_Err
    DoCmd.Echo False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Sales by Sales Type Export"
    **DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdOutputToExcel**
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Sales by Sales Type Export"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.Echo True
    Exit Sub

    C4_Err:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.Echo True
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

Note, this code has been working in this database for 12 years through all MS Access upgrades up until recently. The query opens in datasheet view, but I now get this error message:

“[DatabaseName] can’t save the output data to the file you’ve selected.”

This code has never required a file to select. It is a built-in Microsoft Access function that replaced an old 'DoMenuItem' that was used back in access 2.0 and Access 95.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Cilla

Comment: I've never even seen this RunCommand used. Try DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet.

Comment: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` is best way to transfer data from table/query to excel file. You can also use `DoCmd.Output` method but it has limitation of records (65,000) to export.

Comment: I've been coding Access since 2005. I have never used Echo. I prefer CurrentDb.Execute so don't have to be concerned with warning popups.